# Comma in URL works fine on one IIS but not another

Tags: url, iis

I have a URL with a comma in it. I know that comma is not a legal URL character but my question is - why does this URL work fine on one computer whereas it fails on another? Both are Windows boxes running IIS.

Comment: what is that URL, by the way >?

Comment: http://localhost/foo/bar-Abc,Xyz